# how to fix error in re-installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had  `sql server` installed in my laptop. I planned to download an update of `sqlr2`  since I wa not able to attach my previous database in `sql server 2008` since it is a `661 version`. The update didn't finish as expected hence I decided to uninstall `sql server 2008` by deleting it in the control panel.

Now when I tried re-installing `sql server 2008` back, I am getting following error prompt

https://imageshack.com/i/1qu5vzj
http://imageshack.com/a/img62/3218/u5vz.jpg

When I click on continue option, it again comes back to the same promot

Can anyone help me how to fix this error so i can install `sql server 2008` again in my laptop?

Comment: Can you post the `error log`. It is located at `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\Log\.`

Comment: thinking that not deleting the folder microsoft sql server in my program files ive plan to delete it so i can't view what you're telling me

Comment: this is what i've seen in the error log http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1158/2yh7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about .Net framework 4 . your windows is x86 or x64?
try to install it without using sql server 2008 install package base on your OS system type.

Comment: i've tried repairing or updating my microsoft net framework but after it, nothing happens it is still the same. the error this prompted. my OS is windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Delete the directory C:\Users\[user id]\AppData\Local\MicrosoftCorporation\Microsoft SQL Server and Try re installing it

Comment: i can't see what you've telling sir. this is what i've seen is this sir http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2193/gx94.jpg

Comment: this what i've seen on the %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\1000\Setup Bootstrap\Log\. http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/4527/6l6w.jpg